# Java Creating an Object of Class

Tags: java

Teacher gave us a homework. My question is how to create a Object of a class.

We have a stack interface like this. I coded the stack on the another class named `Stacks`

```
public interface StackInterface<T> {
    public void push(T newEntry);
    public T pop();
    public T peek();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public boolean isFull();
    public void clear();
}
```

I have classes named `Pen` `Book` and `Eraser`.

I have to create stacks like this. Parameterized with class names.

```
public class TestClass {

    Stacks<Pen> sPen=new Stacks<Pen>();
    Stacks<Book> sBook=new Stacks<Book>();
    Stacks<Eraser> sEraser=new Stacks<Eraser>();

    Pen pen=new Pen();
    Book book=new Book();
    Eraser eraser=new Eraser();

}
```

But I cant push anything to stacks. I have to create a pen object in the pen class. I created getter like this.

```
public class Pen {
    private Object name="Pen";
    public Object getName() {
        return this.name;
    }    
}
```

Then I tried to push this item to stack in the TestClass. Please note that I know it returns Object. I just tried.

```
sPen.push(pen.getName());
```

But it still gives error.
Basically I want to create a `Pen` object.

Comment: If it's *a* stack, why do you name it `Stacks`, and not `Stack`? If you want us to explain why your code causes an error, then post the code, and post the error.

Comment: It is just a name of the class. It is implementation of stackinterface. It can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sPen` object is a stack of type `Pen` so you can't push `Object` onto it (which `getName()`) returns.

Instead you can push the pen onto the stack like so

```
sPen.push(pen);
```

Comment: Yeah I know but this is what I tried. Basically I want to create a Pen object

Comment: `new Pen()`, this creates a Pen object. (You already did create one with the name `pen`)

Comment: I dont know what to do. When I convert this object to String, it should return "Pen".

Comment: You can override the toString() method and make it return the "Pen"

Comment: LeoN how can I do this?

Comment: You can also change the type of the member `name` and method `getName` to string, then when you call `getName` you get your string

Comment: @Umut you need to clarify a bit better what you want to accomplish, possibly show the code you want to execute and tell us the result you expect

Comment: Thanks for the help pushing class itself (I mean class object pen) and overriding toString is worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating Stacks of type Pen and not type String

Stacks sPen=new Stacks();

sPen.push(new Pen())